# NHibernate - Identity Column

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, auto-increment

I have declareted the fallowing Mapping for NHibernate:

```
<class name="Sales" table="Sales" lazy="false"  >
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid">      
                    <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
  <version name="ObjectVersion" column="ObjectVersion"/>
    <property name="Number" column="Subject" type="String" length="255"  />
    <property name="Text" column="Body" type="String" length="50" not-null="true"  />
</class>
```

I should now add a additional Column called Key which is defined as an AutoIncrement-Column. Can someone give me a tip how I have to declare this column? This Column has not to be the primary-key - i need only a additional column which has a integer which count up for each record.

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards, Thomas

Comment: If your current GUID ID is valid, why do you need a numeric ID as well? I guess the other question would be, why not use the numeric ID as your PK (if you need it) and make the GUID an alternate key?

Comment: My system has only Guid's as PK's. In this Table, I need a Integer-ID. This ID should be unique and autoincremented. With this ID the user is working - it is in fact some kind of a "human readable id".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using SQL Server? If yes, then just create an Identity column `ALTER TABLE Sales ADD Key INTEGER Identity(1,1)` Then map it as a normal property. It will not be the primary key but it will auto-increment.

Comment: That's a pretty good suggestion..this could probably be done with a database-object mapping as well, to keep everything in the "nhibernate world"...reference can be found here: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/16/nhibernate-mapping-ltdatabase-objectgt.aspx